# What is the best way to inject extremely long html snippets into a single page app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I'm building a fairly simple single page application, mostly it's just a couple of views where users save and work with some local storage data. I opted not to use any templating framework because it's mostly pretty simple JavaScript/jQuery, but maybe it would be worthwhile to use backbone or something. Right now it's just a single index.html and a few .js files.

There is one view in this application however that I'm not sure how to proceed with. It's really mostly just text, a lot of html text. Ten chapters of rules mostly. My question is, what is the best format to keep this text in that lets it still be workable and easy to inject when the user clicks that chapter? Right now I just have a json object for each chapter with a crazy long string with the html for the text in it, but that's proving less than ideal.

So what is the best way to work with huge chunks of html instead of just really long strings? Ideally I could keep each chapter as a separate file to make them easier to update.

Comment: What language do you use server-side?

Comment: How about server-stored files? You could pull the HTML in separately with AJAX / JS-templating-engine-that-supports-remote-partials - your current data structure could have a property with the URL of the file with your already written HTML data which you pull in at render time, and load into the element of your choice.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JB What's the performance improvement in pulling html from server using ajax and injecting it over injecting from `localStorage`?

Comment: @TJ: getting the html from localStorage would be orders of magnitude faster than getting it from the server, especially when the internet is flaky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'best' way is the simplest way (and it usually is), use jQuery:

```
$("#chapterDiv").load("Chapters/Chapter1.html");
```

Comment: For anyone curious [how this approach might affect your SEO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693244/jquery-load-and-seo-anyone-got-a-decent-answer)..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple solution is to store the long content as an HTML page and simply load the content in an IFrame where you need to display it. You can control the placement of the IFrame on your page. You simply set the src attribute of the IFrame to the location of that document.

I know IFrame are not "a la mode" but sometimes a simple solution is what you need.